# $n$ fold convolution tends to zero a.e. if $\|f\|_{L^1}<\infty$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, convolution

Let $f\geq 0$ satisfy $\int_\mathbb{R} f < 1$. Let $f_n$ be the $n$ time convolution of $f$ by itself. 
Then I want to show  $f_n \rightarrow 0$ a.e. as $n\rightarrow \infty$.

We can clearly obtain that $f_n \rightarrow 0$ in $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. But how to prove a.e. convergence?

Comment: I guess we should use that every subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ has a further subsequence converging to $0$ a.e. (because of the $L^1$ convergence).

Comment: If you could use a subsequence argument based on the $L^1$ convergence, then *every* $L^1$ convergent sequence would converge a.e. But this is of course false. The flaw here is that the topology of a.e. convergence does not have the nice structure that you are trying to exploit. Instead you need to basically argue that the whole sequence is already converging so rapidly in $L^1$ that it must itself converge a.e. (Extracting such a rapidly converging subsequence is how one proves that an a.e. convergent subsequence exists in the first place.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a general result which says that an $L^p$ converging sequence has a sub sequence which converges almost everywhere. If you look at the proof (or see below), you will see that it actually holds for the whole sequence,if the convergence is "fast enough", for exponential.

In your example, let $\alpha =\| f \|_1 <1$. Since each $f_n$ satisfies $f_n\geq 0$, we can apply the monotone convergence theorem to get
$$
\int \sum_n f_n \, dx =\sum_n \int f_n \, dx =\sum \|f_n\|\leq \sum \alpha^n <\infty.
$$

But an integrable function is finite almost everywhere, so that $\sum f_n <\infty$ almost everywhere. In particular, $f_n \to 0$ almost everywhere.

Note that I used above that $\|f_n\|_{L^1}\leq \alpha^n$ in which follows from the standard estimate for convolution on $L^1$.